# Is it possible to connect a swift iOS app to Ethereum?

Tags: dapp-development, testnets, ios

Is it possible (and in that case how?) to connect an iOS app, build with swift using xcode, to an Ethereum testnet? So for instance a user would be able to login and set or get a value which is saved on the Ethereum test blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Run a node using [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) or [Parity](https://parity.io/).

Then utilise a library such as [JSONRPCKit](https://github.com/bricklife/JSONRPCKit) to communicate with the node using the [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) implemented by these clients.

Comment: Do you have a more detailed example of how to do this?

Comment: @Frederikke - https://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.html - you can simply make `GET` or `POST` requests: https://imgur.com/a/inmxH (some library may potentially be handier)

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to connect with Ethereum with [web3swift](https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift). This lib is not official from Ethereum but This lib can connect with Ethereum blockchain. For more reference hit this link
https://medium.com/@shivangpandey195/getting-started-with-web3swift-1a2454481f70 and implement web3swift lib in your XCode project.

Comment: Agreed with above comment. @shivang Please consider to improve your answer